# order_by Levenshtein Distance in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to order_by Levenshtein distance on a (small) set of rows returned by an endpoint used for searching. My setup:

- sqlalchemy=='1.3.19'
- Postgres Engine 11.3

My initial approach with `Model`:

```
class Model(Base):
    id = Column(...)
    name = Column(...)


class Child(Column):
    id = Column(...)
    model_id = Column(...)
    model = relationship("Model", backref='children', ...)


class Child2(Column):
    id = Column(...)
    model_id = Column(...)
    model = relationship("Model", backref='child2s', ...)


db: Session = get_session()
q = (
    db.query(Model)
    .options(joinedload(Model.child2s), joinedload(Model.children))
    .filter(Model.children.has(id=12345))
    .order_by(text("LEVENSHTEIN(model.name, 'SomeString')")) <<< this is what caused an error
)

res = q.all()
```

and here is the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) missing FROM-clause entry for table "model"
```

This failed because the joinedload options introduced an alias to my model such that `model.name` is now named `anon_1_model_name`. Because the `order_by` is one of a list of join/filter operations that I'm applying to the query based on incoming requests' parameters, the alias of the `model` table will not be known at runtime. Is there a good way of approaching sorting using the Postgres Levenshtein function?

Answer (score 4):

As usual, SqlAlchemy has exceeded my expectations. The right syntax is:

```py
q = (
    db.query(Model)
    .options(joinedload(Model.child2s), joinedload(Model.children))
    .filter(Model.children.has(id=12345))
    .order_by(func.levenshtein(Model.name, 'SomeString'))
)
```

Comment: Hi! What is the import for func.levenshtein ?

Comment: @SidoShiro92 from sqlalchemy import func